# How can I wait to execute an event in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, twitter, settimeout

I'm trying to make an program that searches twitter for specific hashtags and if there is an image related to it display the image.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to leave a picture on the screen for a short period of time, say 5 seconds or so. Currently with each event the new image gets posted. I tried using setTimeout but I couldn't seem to get it to work. I don't know if this is possible since they are events but I am not all too familiar with javascript. I tried googling for this and searching stack overflow but I couldn't find anything that seemed to relate specifically to this. Thanks in advance for any responses. I apologize if this question seems to be yet another question about making javascript wait. Below is the code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

TwitterPackage = require('twitter');
Open = require('open');

var secret = {
    consumer_key: 'key',
    consumer_secret: 'secret',
    access_token_key: 'token_key',
    access_token_secret: 'token_secret'
}


var Twitter = new TwitterPackage(secret);
var images = []

Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: '#someTag'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
    var url = tweet.entities.media[0]       
    if (url.media_url){
        if (images.indexOf(url.media_url) < 0){
            io.emit('change picture', url.media_url, tweet.text);
            images.push(url.media_url);
            //What I tried for timeout
            /*
            comment out the above io.emit
            then call 
            displayImage(url.media_url);
            */
        }
    }
  });

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

});

//What I tried for setTimeout
function displayImage(url){
    setTimeout(function(){
        io.emit('change picture', url);//, tweet.text);
    }, 5000)
}
```

I added in what I tried for setTimeout as per your request. It delays but it basically just sets everything 5 seconds behind what it should be rather than delaying 5 seconds per image.

I ended up being able to fix it client side.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = [];
        var tweets = [];
        var socket = io();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            socket.on('change picture', function(url, text){
                images.push(url)
                tweets.push(text);
            });
            var DELAY = 5000;
            setInterval(function(){
                if (images.length >= 1){
                    var currImage = images.pop(0);
                    var currTweetText = tweets.pop(0);
                    $('#imageView').attr('src', currImage);
                    $('#tweetText').text(currTweetText);
                    console.log(currImage);
                    console.log(currTweetText);
                }
                console.log('LENGTH:' + images.length);
            }, DELAY);
        });
    </script>
```

I believe this is similar to the suggested way of doing it but I just took a shortcut by doing it on the client side. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Please show us your attempt with `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but need some minor changes to make it work.

The problem is that your code is creating multiple independent timers. The image updates are not coordinated with each other. So one solution is to create a single central timer that updates the image. In my example, you add images (url) to an array buffer. The timer then pulls them off (shift) in the order in which they were added.  There are a number of way you could do this, but this should get you started int he right direction.

**Run the code snippet to try**

```js
var images = [];

// append images to the buffer
function addImage(url) {
  images.push(url);
  if (!window.image.src) updateImage();
}

// central timer 
function updateImage() {
  if (images.length > 0) {
    window.image.src = images.shift();
    window.caption.innerHTML = (new Date()).toTimeString();
  }
}

// start the timer
setInterval( updateImage, 4000);


// add some test images
addImage( 'http://lorempixel.com/g/200/100/sports');
addImage( 'http://lorempixel.com/g/200/100/food');
addImage( 'http://lorempixel.com/g/200/100/animals');
addImage( 'http://lorempixel.com/g/200/100/city');
addImage( 'http://lorempixel.com/g/200/100/nightlife');
```

```html
  <img id="image">
  <div id="caption"></div>
```